# Insulating tape on top of SMDs

Tags: insulation

Is it a good or bad idea to insulate solder joints on a PCB using insulating tape, or Kapton tape. And should each joint be taped individually or to tape on across a whole area?

For example, when a power supply has some live wires soldered on and are normally exposed on the other side. And there is another device in proximity that can "push" on the PSU, potentially shortening the leads.

To clarify, I mean leaving the tape when a device is operating, not just during rework.

Comment: What's the purpose, to keep someone from getting shocked?  If so there are lots of regulations on how that should be done.  It's way better to do it with some type of enclosure than with tape.

Comment: What problem do you think you need to solve? We can't tell you whether a proposed solution is good or bad without knowing what the problem is.

Comment: The purpose is having some other board in proximity to not short the leads when pressed together. At least, that is one of the possible purposes I am stumbling on.

Comment: Isolate the wires then!

Comment: It would be better to make it so that the device *cannot* be pushed onto the other circuitry. If you cannot make enough space around the power supply, can you interpose a securely-mounted insulator, strong and thick enough that it cannot be pierced, such as blank PCB material?

Comment: If there's motion involved, the tape will fray through or come unstuck. Conformal coating or potting is the right answer.

Comment: @Jakey I took the OP's question to imply that the solder joints on the back of the PCB where the wires are attached are the "danger" points.

Comment: Very vague question.

Comment: If you can tolerate and recover from any situation that might occur if the tape fell off, have a field day. If you can't, I'd find another approach.

Comment: sometimes fireproof card or plastic shield is used in circumstances like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In production, this kind of insulation is often achieved with a plastic sheet between the parts (for example, between the solder side of the PCB and the enclosure).  The sheet is held (or loosely captured) by the mounting hardware (screws, standoffs, and such).  Usually, the sheet doesn't have adhesive (or doesn't rely solely on adhesive).